# After compiling and packaging with Flutter build web and deploying the server, a blank page appears on the Alipay app

Tags: flutter, web, alipay, alibaba

Projects created with Flutter, after being compiled and packaged with Flutter build web -- web renderer html, are deployed to nginx servers. They can be opened normally on PC browsers, in mobile browsers, and on WeChat apps, but they are blank when opened on Alipay, Alibaba sellers apps, Test address: https://batGPS.huangshengcai.work/myapp/  This is the deployed website, which is a newly created simple demo project. Is there any special configuration that needs to be handled?

Is there anyone to help？